# Archive Failed in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

The `pg_wal` folder is getting bigger and bigger, and when I query the `archiver` the file is not archived.

```
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_archiver;
 archived_count | last_archived_wal | last_archived_time | failed_count |             last_failed_wal              |       last_failed_time        |          stats_reset          
----------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------
              0 |                   |                    |        19404 | 000000010000000E00000018.00000028.backup | 2019-09-03 11:35:07.161632+08 | 2019-08-30 09:58:19.943897+08
(1 row)
```

The message from the failed archive command was:

```
test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/000000010000001D00000024 && cp pg_wal/000000010000001D00000024 /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/000000010000001D00000024 cp: cannot create regular file '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/000000010000001D00000024': No such file or directory
```

In the master's `postgresql.conf` file there is an `archive_command`

```
test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/%f
```

and this path `var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/%f` is a path in the slave server which I would like to archive to. Then I run the `pg_basebackup` in the replicate server to replicate the database over. The data did replicate over to the replicate server, but in the master server the WAL files are not archived when I check in `pg_stat_archiver`.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look into the server log file, there you will see an error message and the standard error output from `archive_command`.

That will tell you what is wrong so that you can fix it.

Once the problem is fixed, PostgreSQL will archive the WAL files and things will go back to normal.

After some investigation, it turns out that you configured `archive_command` to write the WAL files to the `pg_wal` directory of the slave server, where it collides with the slave's WAL files.

You have to write your WAL archives somewhere else, *not* into the slave's data directory.

Comment: I followed this site to do my replication https://xploit29.com/2018/11/04/setup-streaming-replication-with-postgresql-10/

Comment: This is a very useful answer, specially because Postgres does not log in file by default (which I didn't figure out before). The config file has commented all the settings you will need to solve a similar issue.

Comment: @RicarHincapie I am confused by what you write. This is not about the log file where PostgreSQL says how it is doing (`logging_collector` and `log_destination`), but the transaction log (WAL) that is needed to recover after a crash.

Comment: Oh yes. It's just that to debug the problem you mentioned the Psql logs, and those need to be config to be available in files. I though it was worth it to let the comment about how key logs are here and that you need to configure them first hand.